# Use Import-Csv to read changable column Titles by location

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I'm trying to see if there is a way to read the column values in a csv file based on the column location. The reason for this is the file I'm being handed always has it's titles being changed...

For example, lets say csv file `column A` (via excel) looks like the following:

```
ColumnOne
ValueOne
ValueTwo
ValueThree
```

Now the user changes the title:

```
Column 1
ValueOne
ValueTwo
ValueThree
```

Now I want to create an array of the first column. Normally what I do is the following:

```
$arrayFirstColumn = Import-Csv 'C:\test\test1.csv' | where-object {$_.ColumnOne} | select-object -expand 'ColumnOne'
```

However, as we can see if `ColumnOne` is changed to `Column 1`, it breaks this code. How can I create this array to allow an interchangeable column title, but the column location will always be the same?

Comment: `Import-Csv 'C:\test\test1.csv'|%{$_.PSObject.Properties|select -Index 0|% Value}`

Comment: I get the following syntax error: `Cannot bind parameter 'Process'. Cannot convert the "Value" value of type "System.String" to type "System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock".` squiggly line is under the `%` next to the `Value`

Comment: Do you use PowerShell v3? From this error it looks like you use v2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify headers of your own on import:

```
Import-Csv 'C:\path\to\your.csv' -Header 'MyHeaderA','MyHeaderB',...
```

As long as you don't export the data back to a CSV (or don't require the original headers to be in the output CSV as well) you can use whatever names you like. You can also specify as many header names as you like. If their number is less than the number of the columns in the CSV the additional columns will be omitted, if it's greater then the columns for the additional headers will be empty.

If you need to preserve the original headers you could get the header name(s) you need to work with in variable(s) like this:

```
$csv = Import-Csv 'C:\test\test1.csv'

$firstCol = $csv | Select-Object -First 1 | ForEach-Object {
              $_.PSObject.Properties | Select-Object -First 1 -Expand Name
            }

$arrayFirstColumn = $csv | Where-Object {$_.$firstCol} |
                    Select-Object -Expand $firstCol
```

Or you could simply read the first line from the CSV and split it to get an array with the headers:

```
$headers = (Get-Content 'C:\test\test1.csv' -TotalCount 1) -split ','

$firstCol = $headers[0]
```

Comment: I like this answer. If you want the 4th column then `-Header (1..4) | select 4 -skip 1`. Simple solution.

Comment: hmm weird, it's working now. deleting my previous comment. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

One option:

```
$ImportFile = 'C:\test\test1.csv'
$FirstColumn = ((Get-Content $ImportFile -TotalCount 2 | ConvertFrom-Csv).psobject.properties.name)[0]
$FirstColumn

$arrayFirstColumn = Import-Csv $ImportFile | where-object {$_.$FirstColumn} | select-object -expand $FirstColumn
```

Comment: I'm getting a syntax error - Cannot index into a null array. Any reason for this?

Comment: @Matt - Get-Member will list the properties in alphabetical order (you won't know which one is the first column). .psobject.properties.name will list them in the same order they appear in the file and on the objects.

Comment: @mjolinor I forgot there was a reason to not use that.. Thanks for reminding me.

Comment: @FiddleFreak What is used here is the method to get what you are looking for. I would suggest you dial back the code and run it in pieces to see where it is failing for you.

Comment: If your csv has the Type header, you need to make your TotalCount 3.

Comment: I ran it against a test csv and I can't reproduce your results.

Comment: weird, i wonder if it's because you are using a different powershell version? I'm using 3.0... again the issue is here `).psobject.properties.name)`, for whatever reason, this nulls out the entire content.

Comment: removed comments to cleanup some... So with this line `$FirstFileFirstColumn = Get-Content 'C:\Scripts\Tests\test1.csv' -TotalCount 2 | ConvertFrom-Csv` and this line `Write-Host $FirstFileFirstColumn`, I get the following output `@{ColumnOne=ValueOne}`. Now how do I pull that first key in the hash table?

Comment: I'm running V5, but tested this in a Version=3 session.

Comment: alright, here is what I'm using. It works, but hopefully no `,` will be added in any titles...  `$FirstFileFirstColumn = Get-Content 'C:\Scripts\Tests\test1.csv' -TotalCount 1 -Delimiter ','` `$FirstFileFirstColumn = $FirstFileFirstColumn -replace ',',''`

Answer (score 1):

If you are using PowerShell v2.0 then the expression for $FirstColumn in $mjolinor's answer would be:

```
$FirstColumn = ((Get-Content $ImportFile -TotalCount 2 | ConvertFrom-Csv).psobject.properties | ForEach-Object {$_.name})[0]
```

(Apologies for starting a new answer; I do not yet have enough reputation to add a comment to mjolinor's post)